# Recursively summing up elements from a list; Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having trouble converting a recursive piece of code from Java to Python. All this function does is sum up the elements in an array (or list).

```
public static int Summ(int [] arr, size)
{
   if(size == 0)
      return 0
   else
    return arr[size-1] + Summ(arr,size-1);

}  <-- works fine
```

However, in Python, I get this error message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? Thanks!

```
def Sum(arr,size):
   if size == 0:
     return 0
   else:
     return arr[size-1] + Summ(arr,size-1)
```

Comment: Python is not Java. Please post your python code too.

Comment: `Summ`? Did you mean `Sum`?

Comment: Your method signature is `Sum()` but you call `Summ()`. Did you have that defined somewhere too?

Comment: Translating code is generally a bad idea - things that suit one language don't suit another - for example, Python is not suited to recursive implementations of functions like this due to a lack of tail elimination.

Comment: @ Martijin Pieters: Sorry, in my method definition, it should also be "Summ".

Answer (score 5):

You can just use

```
sum(arr)
```

this will return the sum of the values in the list.

Comment: Or any iterable for that matter :)

Comment: This is one of the reasons people would use python instead of java.

Comment: @Woot4Moo -- Or OP is just blindly trying to translate code from one language to another (I don't know Java or if that is a reasonable way to sum an "array" in Java).

Comment: @mgilson it really isn't the correct way to sum an array in java, but it is something i had to write in undergrad :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo - recursive array summation is very appropriate for this site...in that it might cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
def Sum(arr,size):
   if size == 0:
     return 0
   else:
     return arr[size-1] + Sum(arr,size-1)

a=[1,2,3]  
b=Sum(a,3)
print b
```

Prints `6`

Comment: I think the likely answer, given the error, is that the user is passing a string to the function, not a list of integers.

Comment: @Lattyware how do you figure?  If it was a "string" it would come back as unsupported for `str` iirc

Comment: Weird, I would have sworn that was what it said, apparently I'm going mad.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the Python code, it is difficult to tell exactly what is going on, but based upon the error message, your Summ method may be returning a list rather than an int.

If the Summ object is indeed returning an int, then the arr object might actually contain a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this to be "tail" recursive:

```
def Sum(lst):
    if not lst:
        raise ValueError("Summing an empty iterable?  That's nonsense")
    return lst[0]+Sum(lst[1:]) if len(lst) > 1 else lst[0]
```

but the builtin `sum` function is definitely a better bet -- It'll work for any iterable and it will be more efficient and there's no chances of ever hitting the recursion limit using it.

Python's not really built for tail recursion the way many other languages are.  Guido seems to think that it's not worth worrying about since you can always just re-code it as a loop.

Comment: @Anonymous -- It's complexity is not good in most cases -- which is why I say that the "builtin sum function is definitely a better bet".  You have to be a little careful with complexity here as not all operations are equal.  Specifically, slicing is a very fast list operation compared to executing python code.  And it depends on data-type as well.  a `Numpy.ndarray` could use this code and it would be O(N) as a slice doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Is this really tail recursive?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn -- According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), a tail call is one where the recursive call is the last call in the subroutine.  Neglecting the base case, that's exactly what we have here.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is like the `foo1` example in the [Syntactic form section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Syntactic_form) of the Wikipedia article you referenced.  Control has to be returned to the caller to allow `lst[0]` to be added to the result returned.  To make this tail recursive `Sum` would need to be modified to have a second parameter to be used to accumulate the result returned so that only the call to `Sum` would be the value returned.  At least that's what I just learned in the Coursera Scala course.